# Checking solvability of BDQE

Tags: diophantine-equations

Consider a BDQE:

$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0 $$

where $ A,B,C,D,E,F \in \mathbb Z$

Is there a method to determine (prove/disprove) if integer solution(s) to this equation exist(s) without actually calculating it/them?

Comment: This problem is equivalent to finding iteger points on conics.

Comment: And...? :) A little more?

Comment: I guess no. If the equation leads to a pell-like equation , I do not think that there is a way to show that a solution exists without calculating at least one.

Comment: That's a pity...

Comment: Can be reduced to this equation and then use the formula.  The problem is reduced to finding the equivalent of the equation Pell.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the general problem of solvability of Diophantine equations (not only BDQE, all of them) is the content of 10th Hilbert's Problem which was solved with a negative answer (no general algorithm exists). Still, I thought there could be an exception for specific subclasses of DE like BDQE, but again this is not true.

Comment: Just a moment. There IS a method to find all solutions of the equation you have given, but I think there is no way to find out whether solutions exist WITHOUT concrete calculation. The equation you mentioned is however decideable!

Comment: In the sense of a solution, Hilbert wanted, this equation is easy enough that the answer whether an algorithm exists would be "yes".

Comment: I know there is a method to find them. But you cannot determine the existence of the solutions unless you enter into calculating at least one of them.